# Why is Visual Studio saying that I'm trying to convert a string to a boolean when I'm not using a boolean at all? (CS0029)

Tags: c#, .net, string

I'm trying to make a proof-of-concept command-line software for my team, however something isn't right about my code. The compiler is treating the code as if I'm trying to implicitly convert a string to a bool value, yet I'm not using any booleans here at all, and I by no means am trying to convert anything into one.  The following snippet can be used to reproduce the issue:

```
 namespace default {
     class test {
           static void Main() {
             Console.Clear();
             string IsDemoMode;
             Console.WriteLine("Activate Demo Mode? (Y/N)");
             IsDemoMode = Console.ReadLine();

             if (string IsDemoMode = "Y")
             {
               // Demo code...
             } else 
             {
               // Non-Demo Code...
             };
           }
      }
 }
```

The question here is: Why is Visual Studio thinking I'm trying to convert a string to a boolean when I'm not even close to doing that? Does the compiler expect a boolean to be there instead of a string?

Comment: `if (string IsDemoMode = "Y")` should be `if (string IsDemoMode == "Y")` ... your current code is an **assignment**.

Comment: @Filburt Thanks for your help, looks like the issue's fixed now. Just for clarification though, why did it matter if there was just 1 or 2 = signs? My understanding was that '==' and '=' were the same thing.

Comment: @MeowcatMcMeowXVIII there is a difference between the assignment and equals. You still may use both in your if like "if ( (somestring = otherstring) == third string)"

Comment: @MeowcatMcMeowXVIII, it is better to use "equals" in such cases. Please check the sample in my updated answer

Comment: @MeowcatMcMeowXVIII and confirming one of the answers you can get +2 reputation ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using = instead of ==. So string **=** "some text" will give you **string**. And string **==** "some text" will give you **bool**

```
namespace default {
         class test {
               static void Main() {
                 Console.Clear();
                 string IsDemoMode;
                 Console.WriteLine("Activate Demo Mode? (Y/N)");
                 IsDemoMode = Console.ReadLine();

                 if (IsDemoMode == "Y")
                 {
                   // Demo code...
                 } else 
                 {
                   // Non-Demo Code...
                 };
               }
          }
 }
```

UPD. And it is more recommended to use **Equals** in such cases. So you can ignore case if you want, etc.

```
namespace default {
         class test {
               static void Main() {
                 Console.Clear();
                 string IsDemoMode;
                 Console.WriteLine("Activate Demo Mode? (Y/N)");
                 IsDemoMode = Console.ReadLine();

                 if (IsDemoMode.Equals("Y", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                 {
                   // Demo code...
                 } else 
                 {
                   // Non-Demo Code...
                 };
               }
          }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use == instead of = in your if :

```
if (IsDemoMode == "Y")
{
    //Demo mode
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the code to

```
        if(IsDemoMode.ToLower() == "y") 
         {
            // Demo code...
         } 
         else 
         {
            // Non-Demo Code...
         }
```